# Difference between enum and Enumeration

Tags: java, oop, interface, enumeration

Is there any difference between `enum` datatype and `Enumeration` Interface. I have become confused between the two.

I got my answer that they aren't related but that brings me to another question.

We cannot instantiate interface . So what is the significance of this line

```
Enumeration days = dayNames.elements();
```

Heres the complete code containing that line

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class EnumerationTester {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Enumeration days;
      Vector dayNames = new Vector();
      dayNames.add("Sunday");
      dayNames.add("Monday");
      dayNames.add("Tuesday");
      dayNames.add("Wednesday");
      dayNames.add("Thursday");
      dayNames.add("Friday");
      dayNames.add("Saturday");
      days = dayNames.elements();
      while (days.hasMoreElements()){
         System.out.println(days.nextElement()); 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: They're about as similar as "man" and "manatee". `enum` is a syntactic sugar that allows for meaningful constants; `Enumeration` is a class that provides way to go through a collection.

Comment: @Amadan Is Enumeration a class or interface.

Comment: @chetanmehta enumeration is an interface

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**[Enumeration is an interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html)** : An object that implements the `Enumeration` interface generates a series of elements, one at a time. Successive calls to the `nextElement` method return successive elements of the series.

For example, to print all elements of a `Vector<E> v`:

```
for (Enumeration<E> e = v.elements(); e.hasMoreElements();)
       System.out.println(e.nextElement());
```

**[enum is a data type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)**: An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants. The variable must be equal to one of the values that have been predefined for it.

For example, you would specify a days-of-the-week `enum` type as:

```
 public enum Day {
        SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
        THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
    }

   public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     System.out.ptintln(Day.SUNDAY);  // print SUNDAY
  }
```

**Your Second Question:**

> We cannot instantiate interface . So what is the significance of this
>   line

```
Enumeration days = dayNames.elements();
```

`dayNames` is a `Vector`, a collection just like `List`. (There are differences, but that is beyond the scope of the question.). However, when `daynames.elements()` is called, it returns  an enumeration of the components of vector `daynames`. The returned Enumeration object will generate all items added to this vector. The first item generated is the item at `index 0`, then the item at `index 1`, and so on.

Comment: So there is no relationship between the two.

Comment: @chetanmehta i have updated the post to answer your second question. But in future try thinking of posting a new question instead of editing, so that every can see it.

Comment: Besides it being a legacy class, it's not a good idea to use Enumeration, since it uses Vector: stackoverflow.com/a/16747860/2695414

Answer (score 17):

To be short, `Enumeration` is legacy `Iterator` and `Enum` is a data type.

Answer (score 4):

*Enums* are instance controlled classes in java. You can predefine the different flavors, a type can support. For ex.

```
public enum Direction {
    EAST, WEST, NORTH, SOUTH
}
```

defines a type named *Direction* which can be of 4 types. It's not permitted to instantiate these types from outside their type definition. You can check more on *Enum* [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

While *Enumeration* was the old way to iterate through a collection. It has two methods *nextElement* and *hasMoreElements* which are more like *next* and *hasNext* methods of *Iterator* interface. In old APIs like *Servlet* we can still see some methods which return *Enumeration*. For ex.

```
Java.util.Enumeration<String> paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
```

Answer (score 1):

as per the oracle [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

*An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants. The variable must be equal to one of the values that have been predefined for it. Common examples include compass directions (values of NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, and WEST) and the days of the week.*

**example of enum**

```
public class EnumTest {
    Day day;

    public EnumTest(Day day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public void tellItLikeItIs() {
        switch (day) {
            case MONDAY:
                System.out.println("Mondays are bad.");
                break;

            case FRIDAY:
                System.out.println("Fridays are better.");
                break;

            case SATURDAY: case SUNDAY:
                System.out.println("Weekends are best.");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Midweek days are so-so.");
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnumTest firstDay = new EnumTest(Day.MONDAY);
        firstDay.tellItLikeItIs();
        EnumTest thirdDay = new EnumTest(Day.WEDNESDAY);
        thirdDay.tellItLikeItIs();
        EnumTest fifthDay = new EnumTest(Day.FRIDAY);
        fifthDay.tellItLikeItIs();
        EnumTest sixthDay = new EnumTest(Day.SATURDAY);
        sixthDay.tellItLikeItIs();
        EnumTest seventhDay = new EnumTest(Day.SUNDAY);
        seventhDay.tellItLikeItIs();
    }
}
```

**The output is:**

```
Mondays are bad.
Midweek days are so-so.
Fridays are better.
Weekends are best.
Weekends are best.
```

**Enumeration**

The Enumeration interface defines the methods by which you can enumerate (obtain one at a time) the elements in a collection of objects.

**example of enumeration**

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class EnumerationTester {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Enumeration days;
      Vector dayNames = new Vector();
      dayNames.add("Sunday");
      dayNames.add("Monday");
      dayNames.add("Tuesday");
      dayNames.add("Wednesday");
      dayNames.add("Thursday");
      dayNames.add("Friday");
      dayNames.add("Saturday");
      days = dayNames.elements();
      while (days.hasMoreElements()){
         System.out.println(days.nextElement()); 
      }
   }
}
```

**output**

```
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
```

Comment: Here lies my another confusion . Enumeration is an interface then how can we have days of that data type.

Comment: @chetanmehta which datatype?

Comment: Didn't meant datatype .I meant how come days is storing Enumeration reference type of data.

Comment: @chetanmehta tell me what you understood from the example?

Comment: You just created a Vector object for storing data. Then you wanted to traverse the data by using the Enumeration interface. Enumeration is an interface which many util classes like vector implement.M question is how come we have an object storing instance of Interface just like days here